# Using Materialize Modals with Partial Views (ASP.NET CORE)

Tags: materialize

I was following this guide with Bootstrap, but is there a way to make it work with Materialize?

https://amlblog.net/programming/2016/04/25/bootstrap-modals-and-razor.html

Effectively I just need to insert content into the modal before it displays using a partial view.